# MAC OSX as server cannot be seen by dyndns address - router is blocking access

Tags: tomcat, router, https, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I have OSX running an RTC rational team concert *essentially a Tomcat server* on https port 9443.

In the OSX host file I have 127.0.0.1 mapped to thinkbigapps.dyndns.tv - such that On the mac i can in my browser go to : http://thinkbigapps.dyndns.tv:9443/ccm successfully.

I can access it locally on the Mac by doing : `https://localhost:9443/ccm` and it works no problem also.

I can also access it from my other PCs on my network by doing `https://192.168.0.2:9443/ccm`

I have a dyndns account setup - and it maps thinkbigapps.dyndns.tv to my home IP. Doing a traceroute on the dns brings me to : 90.221.123.21 which is my WAN ip.

The network router has the mac - 192.168.0.2 in the DMZ - and I have a firewall rule written as well to allow the port 9443 inbound to be served by 192.168.0.2 - however if you try visiting : https://thinkbigapps.dyndns.tv:9443/ccm - it does not work with a connection refused error - which suggests the router is blocking the connection and not correctly forwarding it.

My router model is a Sagem F@st 2504.

The mac has its firewall turned off - but Im not an experienced mac user and I want to know if I am missing something.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site works for me. Sounds like your router doesn't handle hairpin NAT very nicely. I suggest you try it from off of your network.

Comment: You have no idea how long I have wasted trying to solve this! Thanks mate!